# Parsing JSON with unknown root element in Swift with swiftlyJSON

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am working in iOS using Swift.  The service I am using returns the following JSON (cut off as the node begins to repeat):

```
    {
        "Ambler Departures: April 15, 2015, 2:57 pm": [
        {
          "Northbound": [
            {
              "direction": "N",
              "path": "R5N",
              "train_id": "564",
              "origin": "Frazer Yard",
              "destination": "Colmar-Link Belt",
              "status": "On Time",
              "service_type": "LOCAL",
              "next_station": "North Broad St",
              "sched_time": "Apr 15 2015 03:27:00:000PM",
              "depart_time": "Apr 15 2015 03:27:00:000PM",
              "track": "2",
              "track_change": null,
              "platform": " ",
              "platform_change": null
            },
            {
              "direction": "N",
              "path": "R5N",
              "train_id": "6566",
              "origin": null,
```

Notice that the root node is created dynamically by the service-- I don't have a way of knowing what it will be as the user can chose departures from one of fifty stations and the time is based on the time on the server, which is likely inconsistent with the time on the user's clock.

I want to extract the data from the Northbound Array, and then a Southbound Array lower in the JSON.

I am getting the data returned form the service but I can't parse correctly.  I can't get past the root node (the dynamic one) to get to the structure inside.

Here's what I am trying:

```
let json = JSON(data:data)
var x = 0
while x < json.count
    {
       let track = json[0]["Northbound"][x]["track"].string                
       println(track)
       x++
     }
```

This results in "nil".  I am stuck...

I know that json[0] is probably wrong since that level of the JSON is not an array. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `json` is a JSON object from SwiftyJSON but you know it's a dictionary with an unknown key, you can find this key with:

```
let theKey = json.dictionary!.keys.first
```

Then access the array:

```
let theArray = json[theKey] as! [[String:AnyObject]]  // array of dictionaries
```

Then `theArray[0]` will be the dictionary with "Northbound" as a key, which contains an array of dictionaries containing the infos.

*(Edited to reflect the correct answer specific to SwiftyJSON.)*

Comment: I understand what you are saying here...  However "keys" is not recognized.  I don't think in the swiftlyJSON library "keys" is part of the JSON class.

Comment: Maybe it was created as an `NSDictionary`? In this case you can cast it to a Swift dictionary. Then you will be able to use this `keys` method. (You can do ALT+CLICK on `json` to know its type)

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong here, but type is JSON.  Declaration that pops up is let json:JSON.  I think you're on the write track.  Alt-clicking on JSON gives me a declaration of public struct JSON.  The library I am using comes highly recommended and I've had no trouble parsing JSON that didn't have this irregularity.  Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Ok, I just edited my answer. Try with this new way. *If it still doesn't work, I'm ok to test it further but I will need access to an URL or a file with a bit of your JSON.*

Comment: That did it!  I should have thought of the ! when you first made the suggestion!  Kudos!